# Multiselect not generating for a json response in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a multiselect drop down list with [THIS](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) plugin. But when I tried to generate the list for a JSON response, it fails and shows nothing.

```
<select id="example26" multiple="multiple" data-role="multiselect">

</select>
```

And the Javascript :

```
function render_ui(resp) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(resp,function(index,obj){
    html += '<option value="'+obj.EmployeePersonal.id+'">'+obj.EmployeePersonal.name+'</option>';

  });
  $('#example26').append(html);

}
```

NB: For drop down lists without multiselect select option, I am able to generate the list !

Comment: You don't seem to be actually *using* the plugin in the code you have provided.

Comment: But Its coming for normal select-option. I think it wont have come without the plugin :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function render_ui(resp) {
  var html = '';
  $.each(resp,function(index,obj){
    html += '<option value="'+obj.EmployeePersonal.id+'">'+obj.EmployeePersonal.name+'</option>';

  });
  $('#example26').append(html);
  $('#example26').multiselect('refresh');
}
```

Comment: same ..not populating the list :/